# Get list of languages spoken in a country from wikidata SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to use SPARQL and wikidata to find all the languages in a country. 
E.g languages in Abuja.

```
#languages in world
SELECT ?Lang ?LangLabel
WHERE {
  ?Lang wdt:P31/wdt:P31* wd:Q34770 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

This gives me a huge dataset, how can I filter it?

Running code: 
**[Wikidata Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23languages%20in%20world%0ASELECT%20%3FLang%20%3FLangLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3FLang%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP31%2A%20wd%3AQ34770%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D)**

EDIT: I'm looking for all languages used in a country not just the offcial languages

Comment: The query should be more country -> language, something like `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?official_language  WHERE {
  ?item 
        wdt:P37 ?officiallanguage ;
        wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 .

  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel . FILTER(lang(?itemLabel)='en')
  ?officiallanguage rdfs:label ?official_language . FILTER(lang(?official_language)='en')
}
ORDER BY ?item ?itemLabel ?official_language`

Comment: if you want to do it for a particular country, just replace the `?item` with the appropriate URI (and remove the second triple pattern which would be redundant) - or use `VALUES ?item {<COUNTRY_URI_HERE> ,,, }

Comment: Can you post a working example of per country sorting?
I want all the languages spoken in a country not only the official Languages

Answer (score 0):

This query makes use of the language used (P2936) property to return the languages spoken in Nigeria:

```
SELECT ?language ?languageLabel
WHERE { 
  wd:Q1033 wdt:P2936 ?language . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

It does not appear to work for cities, however

Answer (score 0):

For official languages, by country:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?countryLabel ?languageLabel
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
           wdt:P37 ?language .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

For all language, by country:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?countryLabel ?languageLabel
{
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
           wdt:P2936 ?language .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```